# How do I handle index out of range errors when parsing large quantities of data in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, null, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a huge amount of data an a `.txt` file that I'm trying to parse to `objects` in a `list` using `Pyhon`. The data structure looks like this for most part, and when it does, the parsing is successful.

```
2315462;3/13/2015 8:00:00 AM;3/13/2015 1:00:00 PM
778241;1/3/2015 12:30:00 PM;1/3/2015 1:00:00 PM
```

As you can see, there's an id, a start time and an end time. It is parsed using this code:

```
my_array_with_objects = []

with open("test.txt", newline='\n') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')

for row in reader:
    my_array_with_objects.append(Employee(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
```

`Employee` being a class that looks like this:

```
class Employee:

def __init__(self, id, time_start, time_end):
    self.id = id
    self.time_start = time_start
    self.time_end = time_end
```

Occasionally though, `time_end` is missing from the data:

```
276908;1/3/20152015 8:00:00 AM
```

At this point the program crashes with an `index out of range` exception. I'm new to Python but heard there is no such thing as a `null` value. Then why does it crash? I assumed that it could be handled with something along the line:

```
if row[2] is None:
    print("error, do things to fix")
```

...but it doesn't trigger. How do I handle these errors? I don't want anything special to happen if the `row[2]` is missing. It's fine with an empty value.

Comment: `if len(row) < expected_length: continue` where the `time_end` is missing should do the trick? And you should also do some form of format check on the times where the length is off, in case it's actually a row you want to keep but there's another field missing or something.

Comment: Nice, worked like a charm. Thanks alot @Torxed. Post it as a real answer if you want me to check it as an answer :)

Comment: give it to Zan. He has a valid point and the proposed solution expands on my idea pretty neatly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a check `if len(row) < 3` as suggested by @Torxed. A better solution might be to rewrite `Employee` class and use the 'splat' operator to expand the row (a list). For missing values an empty string '' is used.

This also covers the cases where both start_time and end_time, or all 3 values are missing.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, id='', start_time='', end_time=''):
        self.id = id
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.end_time = end_time

        # check values and convert to int, datetime...

for row in reader:
    my_array_with_objects.append(Employee(*row))
```

Comment: Sneaky good use of list expansions in junction with default values to solve this problem. Well done :) Just note that this might catch error prone rows where the data in `id` and `start_time` might become incorrect values. It will allow for "eating" those rows, just that the data might be incorrect. Still a good solution tho but flagging for these or handling them later becomes important :)

Comment: @Torxed Thanks! This solution circumvents any error checking. Everything is string, so there are no incorrect values at this point, only missing values. I assume that the author does error checking later, when values are converted to e.g. int and datetime.

Comment: Just to clarify a example regarding incorrect values: https://i.imgur.com/GxQK8r8.png *(This would give false sense that everything is working, but the values are not ID or start-time related, but will work/get eaten by this class)*.

Comment: You are correct, but the question did not involve value parsing, just assignment. I'll a comment line to the script to warn.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cover missing time_end, this should do the trick:

```
for row in reader:
    try:
        my_array_with_objects.append(Employee(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
    except IndexError:
        my_array_with_objects.append(Employee(row[0], row[1], None))
```

You can replace None with a default value or choose how to deal with the missing field however you want in the except block